# No ads shown for android project

Tags: java, android

I have been following [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start#place_an_adview_in_your_main_activity_layout) probably outdated instructions to insert (test) ads to my android project. After I have recompiled the project on a virtual Nexus 5 phone, the app works, but no add-banner is shown.

Maybe there is a problem with the layout file, as my layout file does not look like the example layout file. Here are the relevant parts of my layout file to include the ad-banner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
      ...
      ...


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is the problem related to the layout? How else to figure out why  the ad banner is not shown?

Comment: You are using RelativeLayout attributes for your AdView inside a LinearLayout. It doesn't really matter, but you should probably replace the AdView with a normal View layout to check that it is displayed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a discussion with the OP, it turned out that the CoordinatorLayout and the AdView were both inside a LinearLayout, and the CoordinatorLayout was pushing the AdView off of the screen because its height was "match_parent"

By changing the CoordinatorLayout height to 0dp, and weight to 1, it will grow to fill the remaining space above the AdView instead of taking the entire screen.

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

instead of:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

Comment: No, I still do not see ads after recompiling and restarting the virtual Nexus device ...

Comment: @Alex Hmm... since you are using a `CoordinatorLayout`, does your `LinearLayout` have the correct layout behaviour specified, so that it does not hide under the `AppBarLayout`?

Comment: What is the correct layout behavior for that? I do not know. I am a very beginner with android...

Comment: @Alex Add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `LinearLayout`

Comment: I have that already in the LinearLayout. And I have absolutely no idea what it means ...

Comment: I even added my device as test device to the AdRequest variable, and tried with a real device. Still no ads....

Comment: Why not make a plain main activity with a text box and the ads as their guide. Programming does not happen in a day. well not always anyway.